# Does a question that got closed still count for fulfilling the commitment to make ten posts?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Does a question that got closed still count for fulfilling the commitment to make ten posts?

Comment: The counting of what?

Comment: I *think* the intent is to ask: "Does a question that got closed still count for fulfilling the commitment to make ten posts?"

Comment: @quid: Exactly!

Comment: Glad I got the meaning. Unfortunately. I do not know the answer (I would guess: yes for closed, no for deleted). I recommend you edit your question (for example, just taking my sentence if you like) so that a clarified version  will get visibility again. I meant to suggest an edit but this seems not to work on meta.